# Firebase functions + OAuth redirect url mismatch

Tags: firebase, oauth, google-cloud-functions, gmail-api

I have an issue with following scheme. I have 2 Firebase functions. First one request initialize oAuth client and redirects to url where User should see Google OAuth Consent screen. After approval - necessary code executes.

In Local firebase emulators everything works. But when I've deploy my functions to Firebase functions and trying to use their address - I have an error 400 mismatch.

In Cloud console I have all keys and JS Origins settled.
What it can be? I need the app to be in production?

[image]

Comment: Look at the last line of the error message. The error means that the redirect URL that your app is using does not match what you configured for the OAuth Client ID.

Comment: Thanks for answer @JohnHanley but I understood. The reason is - why?

Redirection url is: https://us-central1-er-4d607.cloudfunctions.net/gmailer_main

And in Google Cloud, Api & Services, Credentials, I have
Authorized JavaScript origins: |
https://us-central1-er-4d607.cloudfunctions.net

Authorized redirect URIs
https://us-central1-er-4d607.cloudfunctions.net/gmailer_main

Comment: When you set up the Client ID, you specify the URLs that can be called for the OAuth redirect (to extract the code value). They do not match what your application is using. Since your post does not include details on your app or how you setup the OAuth Client ID, I can only guess. Search StackOverflow as this problem has been asked many times.

Comment: @JohnHanley I've edited my previous comment and explain mor explicit. Redirect URI and Authorized are the same.

Comment: If they were the same, you would not get the error. Click on `error details`. What is displayed? Once you solve that problem, you mention the term `production`. Depending on which OAuth scopes you are using, Google will need to approve that. Sometimes that requires a security audit. Details matter when posting questions to get a good answer. Your post does not have the details required.

Comment: I've mentioned that in local environment redirection works. When I deploy functions (probably you can say that this is a production environment) - the error occurs.

Comment: That means you must specify a different Redirect URL. You cannot use `localhost` in the cloud for remote connections from other services.

Comment: The term `production` has a special meaning with OAuth Client IDs. Until the OAuth Client is set to production mode, your users will receive a warning message.

Comment: @JohnHanley I believe either I provide lack of information or you do not understand the problem. 

Will try to rephrase. My OAuth App is not published. It's in TEST mode, allowing specific users to see a consent screen. Main code is Firebase Functions, deployed to Firebase. While in local environment and with local redirect it works, when deployed to Firebase with firebase deployed redirect url - I see url mismatch error. The url itself is allowed in Credentials in GCP. 

My Question is: 
* deploying functions to Firebase makes them "production like" and band redirection?

Comment: Your problem is very simple. You have a mismatch between the OAuth Client ID configuration and what the client is using. Yes, using the correct terms is also important. Reading the documentation should help. I have not posted an answer. Only comments to help you provide the details so you can get a good answer. Note: your post lacks the details to answer. Review each comment and update your question. For example, what does the `error details` link tell you? Put that in your question.

Comment: @JohnHanley you know, you are correct :) Problem was really simple. I provided wrong credentials. They were working fine in node environment, but when I deploy, I needed to provide web credentials with correct redirection URI. Thank you sir :) 

After hours of work, have this narrow vision problem :)

Comment: Glad to help. Sometimes simple bugs can be the biggest pains.